# Can`t seem to figure out a way set event.currentTarget to be transferable between event listeners. Any help is appreciated?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onmouseover

I have a HTMl-table with data. I want to make it so when the user hovers over the first data cell of the table, that cell is turned into a checkbox which when clicked collects an id from that table row and can be used to delete said row. If the user moves the mouse out of that data cell it should receive it's previous data and remove the checkbox. If a single checkbox is clicked all should be shown. The problem I have is that with my current code I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'currentTarget')". I've put an "//ERR" at the lines which Chrome thinks are the cause for the error. The HTMl part consists of a simple table with 6 rows and 5 td elements on each row.
Code bellow:

```
let taskTable=document.querySelector('#table_1')  
let tableBody=taskTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')  
let tableRowArr=[]  
for(let i=0;i<tableBody.length;i++){  
    tableRowArr.push(tableBody[i])  
}  
tableRowArr.forEach((row,index) => {  
    let tableRowFirstDataCell=row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]  
    let holdData=tableRowFirstDataCell.innerHTML  
    tableCellsData.push(holdData)  
    tableRowFirstDataCell.onmouseover=(event)=>addCheckboxes(event,row,index) //ERR   
})  
function addCheckboxes(event,target,row,index){
    if(event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.firstChild.tagName==="INPUT"){ //ERR
        event.currentTarget.innerHTML=""
        event.currentTarget.innerHTML=tableCellsData[index]
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener("onmouseover",addCheckboxes())
        event.currentTarget.addEventListener("onmouseout",addCheckboxes(event,target,row,index))
    }
     else if(event.currentTarget.firstChild.tagName!=="INPUT"){
        event.currentTarget.innerHTML=""
        let checkBox=document.createElement("input")
        checkBox.setAttribute("type","checkbox")
        // checkBox.setAttribute("") //<-----  Add styling to checkboxes
        // checkBox.addEventListener("onclick",deleteTask(id))
        event.currentTarget.appendChild(checkBox)
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener("onmouseout",addCheckboxes()) //ERR
        event.currentTarget.addEventListener("onmouseover",addCheckboxes(event,target,row,index))
    }
}
```

Comment: The argument to `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` must be a function, not a call to the function. It shouldn't have `()` after the function name.

Comment: You can't use `removeEventListener` if the listener is an anonymous function.

Comment: Instead of making `row` and `index` arguments to the function, it should get them from `event.currentTarget`